# Fixed headers not working on IE 5 and IE 6

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a requirement to fix headers of a html table. I could fix it By just setting position of the header element to fixed, It did freeze the header on IE 10 and IE 11 but, it did not work on IE 6 and IE 5. If there is any work around for this please let us know. Thanks.

I shared a sample code snippet for your reference at :- 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yb4hqghtqcyrhae/fixed.html?dl=0

**CSS**

```
 .Fixedheader
 {
  position:fixed;              
 }
```

**html**

```
  <table border="1">
  <tr  style="border-collapse:collapse;" bgcolor="#E6E6FA" class="Fixedheader">
```

`

Comment: Still supporting IE5?? Really Surprise.

Comment: Yes we still support IE 5.

Comment: IE5 & IE6 in 2014? You should leave that job :) Seriously!!

Comment: IE5 was released in __June 1998__, it is 16 years old, and as far from modern browsers as the moon is from the Earth. If you really have to support IE5-6, you should consider a separate page for them. To avoid some future struggling you should learn these: CSS Level 1, Dynamic CSS, HTML4, JScript5.0, ActiveX ...  Or rather ask your boss, if (s)he's willing to pay your training for the ancient techniques ; ).

Answer (score 1):

IE didn't support `position: fixed` until version 7. See [this browser support table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility).

You will have to do some combination of absolute positioning and JavaScript if you need to support IE 5 and 6. Those are *really* obsolete -- do you really need to support them with this particular element?

Comment: Yes we still need to support. We a have table element with in a div element, when ever number of rows in the table exceed div element's max-height, scroll bar gets added by default. By default top row of the table is scrollable we want to make it fixed(not scrollable).

Comment: Then you will have to do some JavaScript to determine where the top row should be. Alternatively, you could consider wrapping it in a div or other item and setting the overflow to scroll vertically ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Browser_compatibility)). That gets you much of the impact, with much less pain. IE 6 is only about 3% of web users (if that), and IE 5 is effectively 0%. So, this gets you a lot of bang for the buck on a problem affecting only a very few people.